# Different TOC labels on Chapters and Appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

In a book I am working on, I'd like the TOC entries for chapters to read

```
Chapter 1: foobar        3
```

while for Appendices

```
Appendix 1:  bletch    197
```

Using `tocloft`, the lines

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{: }
```

(together with a line to control width) in my preface does the trick for the chapter name formatting, but unfortunately those lines seem to need to be in the preface, so I can't later redefine `cftchappresnum` when starting to process appendices. I've also tried making the definition of `cftchappresnum` dependent on that boolean:

```
\newboolean{inappendix}
\setboolean{inappendix}{false}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{inappendix}}{Appendix }{Chapter }}
```

and then issuing `\setboolean{inappendix}{true}` just after `\appendix`, but this fails as well (it acts as though `inappendix` is always false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of `\cftchappresnum` must be written to the `ToC` directly to make it effective for the appendix when the `.toc` file is called, i.e.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\protect\appendixname~}}
```

will write the change (use `\protect` to prevent errors during the writing process)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{: }

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\protect\appendixname~}}

\chapter{Foo appendix}

\end{document}
```

I leave the real length specification of `\cftchapnumwidth` to the O.P.

[image]